# Retrieve value from form

Tags: javascript, forms, dojo

My form is like

```
  <form action="javascript:;" method="post" id="reportForm">
    <input type="text" name="as" maxlength="3" />
    --CODE--
 <html:hidden property="reportid" value="${Scope.reportId}" />
    --code--
   </form>
```

I can retrieve values from the form in javascript like

```
    this.form = dojo.byId('reportForm');
    this.as1 = this.form.as;
```

How can i retrieve the value of the html:hidden tag property.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `html:hidden` tag defined in the HTML specification. I don't know dojo but I suppose this syntax will eventually render as `<input type="hidden" name="reportid" value="foo" />` and you would retrieve its value the same way as the other input tag: `this.form.reportid`. You may look with FireBug at the actual DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dojo.formToObject`](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/formToObject) and pass the form id or DOM node as the parameter. You can get an object that contains the values of all the form elements.

```
 var obj = dojo.formToObject("reportForm");
 var id = obj.reportid;
```